# how to change main background color of media elements audio player (black by default) to something lighter?

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am using the MediaElement.js Wordpress plugin and am trying to change the main background color of the audio player (which is black by default) to something lighter so it matches my theme better. I tried replacing "background.png" with my own image, but it didn't work. I am currently only using the player for mp3's, so I'm talking about the 30px tall audio player background color. However, it would be nice to know how to change the color for the video player as well for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

In the mediaplayerelement.css (or minimized version) change the background attribute of the .mejs-container tag.  I'm only using this for MP3 files like you, so I don't know if this also works for the video player or if something else needs to be updated.

```
.mejs-container {
    position: relative;
    background: #000;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}
```